# How to get all inputs from a form using python Scrapy

Tags: python, forms, xpath, scrapy

I need to get all the inputs from a form

```
<form action="/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="SruPnWLxKQsADilCyvGFbRIetmjwBqNgpJVhHZoMfYzkOTdXcaEU">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <label for="username">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
        
    </form>
```

Consider the above code and I need to get only input elements from it. My expression for this operation is `**response.xpath('//form[child::input]').extract()**`. Could someone please help me to correct the expression

My intention is to log in to any website using python request. For that, I'm planning is to scrape all input elements(including hidden inputs) in a form where I will give form name as a parameter to XPath. After that, I can fill the form data with my credentials along with I can pass the csrf token if it present.

My input for this operation is
username, password, and form_name

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ('http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'csrf_token': token,
                                                   'password': 'foobar',
                                                   'username': 'foobar'},
                                         callback=self.scrape_pages)

    def scrape_pages(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

Could some please help me to change the above code based on my requirement. Your time and guidance is appreciated

Comment: To get password and username inputs, use `//input[@class="form-control"]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.xpath('//form//input').extract()
```